# Winform chart gets a red cross after removing ChartArea

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a chart which I populate with up to four chartareas and one serie per chartarea...

I also have a delete button to remove last added chartarea and serie, it works fine until the last one  Then I got a red cross over my chartcontrol.

```
private void DeletePic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = chart1.ChartAreas.Count;
        try
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
            if (count > 0)
            {
                chart1.Series[count-1].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series.RemoveAt(count - 1);
                chart1.ChartAreas.RemoveAt(count - 1);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can hide the chart control when all the areas are deleted.

Comment: it actually helped! thank you!